# How to read coordinates of a DIV while it is being dragged ? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to read the coordinates of a <div> while it is being dragged and compare it to a static <div> and if at all their positions intersect each other while dragging, it should show some message. I want to accomplish this on web using jquery or javascript. Thanks in advance.

code might be something like this (just a random code)

```
 function onDivDragged(e){


     var elemOffset=$("#"+e.target.id).offset();
       var elem2Offset=$("#elem2Id").offset();

      if(parseInt(elem2Offset.top.replace("px",""))==parseInt(elemOffset.top.replace("px","") &&  parseInt(elem2Offset.left.replace("px",""))==parseInt(elemOffset.left.replace("px","")))
       {
       alert("intersection occurred");
       }

}
```

Comment: why -1 ? i didn't get it ?

Comment: Sounds good - now tell us what you've already tried, rather than asking us to do all the work for you

Comment: I had tried comparing the coordinates of 2 <div>s but not while dragging, so not sure what would i write.

Comment: Post your code for dragging. If someone wants to answer he would need something to base the answer on.

Answer (score 1):

If using jQuery UI is an option then you can use jQuery UI Draggable to achieve this.

Further details are available here http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

During `drag` event get cordinates of div getting dragged and compare it to the static div and compute intersection.

Answer (score 1):

use below javascript code to get the coordinate position of the element

```
var elemant = document.getElementById('elementID'),
    left = element.offsetLeft, // returns  X coords
    top = element.offsetTop;  // returns Y coords
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "ondragover" event instead of manually checking coordinates.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can get offset of any element using jquery.

```
var offset = $("#some-element").offset();

// log the values
console.log("top: " + offset.top+ "left: " + offset.left);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/css/base.css?v=1">
<style>
    #myDiv
    {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: Red;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myDiv").draggable({
            start: function (e, ui) {
                var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                $("#start").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                $("#end").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
            },
            drag: function (e, ui) {
                var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
                var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
                $("#current").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
            }

        });
    });


</script>
</head>
<body>
start Position:<span id="start"></span>
<br />
End Position:<span id="end"></span>
<br />
Dragging Position<span id="current"></span>
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```